# Poor OpenGL graphics Quality on First Generation iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am using NinevehGL graphics library for rendering 3D models for an iOS application.
The rendering is quite good on the simulator and works well on iPhone 4S, iPad 2 and other recent devices.

But the quality is not as good on first generation iPad.

see the images

**iPad(First Gen) As well as iPhone 3GS:**

[image: iPad version]

**iPhone 4S:**

[image]

Basically the gradient effect on iPad is very poor.. I am not worried about the antialiasing at the moment,, but I am worried about the clear difference in the gradient change of color.. in the first image one can clearly see the dark and bright regions.. but in the second image such regions are not so distinct.

Is this a device specific thing or are there any build settings that I can change to get better graphics for this version of iPad?

Comment: Did you scale your context?  Running at double pixels on a non-retina device forces anti-aliasing.

Comment: Could be a normalisation issue, if the normals aren't unit length, but the shaders used on the later devices are normalising.

Comment: Do you use low precision variables in your shader? Iirc, they are handled a bit different across the devices and you might end up with such artifacts.

Comment: The effect is same without shaders.. At the moment I am more worried about the clear distinction between dark and bright sides.. I was expecting it to be smooth gradient effect. Anti-aliasing will be dealt later...

Comment: Are you rendering in OpenGL ES 1.1 for iPad and 3GS? and shader for newer devices?

Comment: I believe, iPad first Gen support openGL ES 1.1 only. So I am rendering in openGL ES 1.1.. The effect is same with or without shaders.